# how to format a float like 0#.## in java?

Tags: java, string, formatting

I get an input from the user. I want to print it in this format:

```
0#.##
```

or

```
##.##
```

how do I do this in java?

Today I'm using:

```
padWithZeroRightToPeriod(product.formats[index],Float.parseFloat(currentPrice));
```

and

```
private String padWithZeroRightToPeriod(String serverFormat, float unformattedNumber) {
  int nDigits = getNumberOfDigitsAfterPeriod(serverFormat);
  String floatingFormat = "%4." + nDigits + "f";
  String formattedPrice = String.format(floatingFormat, unformattedNumber);

  return formattedPrice
}
```

but it converts `08.56` to `8.56`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two decimal places, and at least two whole digits, with leading zeroes:

```
String floatingFormat = "%05.2f";
```

- The `0` pads the string with zeros instead of spaces.
- The `5` is the minimum total field width, including the whole, fractional and decimal point parts.
- The `2` is the exact number of decimal places to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

try using DecimalFormatter

```
        float f= 3.44f;                 
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.##");    
        System.out.println("formatted  value::"+ df.format(f));
```

==============================================================================
updated your function

```
private static String padWithZeroRightToPeriod(String serverFormat, float unformattedNumber) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(serverFormat);    
        return df.format(unformattedNumber);
    }
```

calling function

```
padWithZeroRightToPeriod("00.##",3.44f)
```